# Return content type not supported from Twilio SMS api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, twilio, twilio-api

Currently im working on a project which need SMS retrieve functionality added to the system. I have use spingboot to build the application.All the implementation done and i have followed the all necessary configurations on twillio to retrieve sms from client. When i send a sms to Twilio api, it state the `Unsupported Media Type` in the debugger. I am sending also the required content type to api. **This happens when im sending an sms to number which is provided by twilio. But postman calls to the application working fine**.

```
package com.crustykrabs.application.service;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import static spark.Spark.*;
import com.twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse;
import com.twilio.twiml.messaging.Body;
import com.twilio.twiml.messaging.Message;

@RestController
public class TextMessageController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/messages/textmessages/receive", consumes = "application/xml", produces = "application/xml")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> receive() {
            Body body = new Body
                    .Builder("The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!")
                    .build();
            Message sms = new Message
                    .Builder()
                    .body(body)
                    .build();
            MessagingResponse twiml = new MessagingResponse
                    .Builder()
                    .message(sms)
                    .build();
            return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).body(twiml.toXml());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like what you are sending to your own controller (and not Twilio) isn't `application.xml` but just a regular form submit. What request are you sending to your controller? IN show just remove the `consumes` from your mapping. You are doing a regular form submit and not sending xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, api call is best option. Please do implementation with the published API using `RestTemplate` like below.

```
public void sendOTP() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String message = "Your PIN for account verification is 123456";
    String user = "******405e4c****19d0******";
    String password = "******";
    String smsurl = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+user+"/Messages.json";

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("From", "+1334384****");
    map.add("To", "+999999999");
    map.add("Body", message);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

    try {
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(user, password));
        Object response = restTemplate.postForObject(smsurl, httpEntity, Object.class);
        LOG.info("Sms Response: {}", gson.toJson(response));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not think the client specified the content-type. Please add `content-type: application/xml`.

and if you have a spring boot, you can fix it by adding the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
     <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thankz won..But I am adding the content type to the response as contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

Comment: However, the message in the response body is specified as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. I would like to see your request/response in detail.

Comment: when postman request sent to the api, it comes as content-type: application/xml. I think issue is with the twilio api.

Comment: Is this situation familiar to you? https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-java

Comment: I have followed that tutoral using springboot instead of spark

Comment: If you look at the code above, it seems that you are in a situation where api call is not requested and responded.

If you only want to use spring boot, you should use [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).